# Search and replace with wildcard text in Notepad++

Tags: search, replace, notepad++, wildcard

I'm using Notepad++ and I'm trying to remove a number of lines from a file with the following example text:

```
<title lang="en">&lt;a href=\"/movies/randomtext1/\"&gt;randomtext1</title>
<title lang="en">&lt;a href=\"/movies/randomtext2/\"&gt;randomtext2</title>
```

I'd like to remove/replace the `&lt;a href=\"/movies/randomtext1/\"&gt;` section and just leave this on each line `<title lang="en">randomtext1</title>`

I'm just not sure now to enter the "wildcard" expression for the random text bit.

Hope that makes sense :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

Find what: `&lt;.+?&gt;`
Replace with: `NOTHING`

Answer (score 1):

Try a regular expression search/replace:

- **Find what:** `\&lt;a href=\\"/movies/(.*)/\\"\&gt;\1`
  Here we need to escape several characters that have a special meaning for regular expressions: `& \` . The wildcard is the `(.*)`, which means any (`.`) character repeated zero or more times (`*`). Because of the parentheses  we can reference that part of the search with `\1` in the search itself and in the repacement, too.
  Instead of `.*` inside the parentheses you might also try `[^/]*` (everything which is not a slash).
- **Replace with:** `\1`
- Check **Regular Expression** in the lower left.